# Синтаксическая ошибка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import copy
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import nltk


class AnnotationClass(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super(AnnotationClass, self).__init__()
        self.filepath = file

    def parse(self, f4):
        lemms = list()
        i="{"
        j="}"
        obj = []

        while len(f4) > 0:
            lemms.append(f4[f4.index(i) + 1: f4.index(j)])
            f4 = f4[f4.index(j) + 1:]

        return lemms
```

использую класс вот так:
`a = AnnotationClass("")`, пишет ошибку:

```
name 'AnnotationClass' is not defined
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: версия python 3

Comment: Используете класс вот так где?

Comment: Скорее всего `a = AnnotationClass("")` было вызывано до того как класс AnnotationClass был объявлен. Кст, с питона3 не нужно явно у классов писать наследование от object, а вызов конструктора предка `super(AnnotationClass, self).__init__()` теперь можно вызывать так `super().__init__()`. А еще можно было не вызывать конструктора у наследника object

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю в чем была проблема , но она решилась путем перезагрузки jupyter notebook

Answer (score -1):

**Вот так работает**

```
class AnnotationClass(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super(AnnotationClass, self).__init__()
        self.filepath = file

    def parse(self, f4):
        lemms = list()
        i="{"
        j="}"
        obj = []

        while len(f4) > 0:
            lemms.append(f4[f4.index(i) + 1: f4.index(j)])
            f4 = f4[f4.index(j) + 1:]

        return lemms

a = AnnotationClass("")
```

Comment: Где ошибка была?

Comment: Возможные варианты : класс импортировался из другого модуля не правильно или инстанс  создан до описания класса